# Operating System not found (Grub error)

Tags: 14.04, grub2, kernel, grubrescue, ubuntu-gnome

Certainly after a reboot my pc I am getting following message in a grub welcome screen 
**GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1 

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else tab lists possible device or file vompletions 
 grub>** 

*I was surfing internet and learning methods to speed up the OS. So I did removed obsolete softwares from Synaptic Package Manager. I completely removed grub as well.*

Comment: " I completely removed grub as well." there is your problem. And w h y did you decide that was a good idea?! Please  install grub from a live dvd or form command line.

Comment: Now I am on grub menu, can i install grub from here. And right now I have no live boot mediums

Answer (score 0):

So you've messed with GRUB.

One easy, fool-proof solution (if not the fastest) is to install [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A1st_option_:_get_a_disk_including_Boot-Repair). Follow their instructions.

If you've managed to get a shell prompt, you might be able to run `apt-get` commands. Or grab an Ubuntu live CD (tricky if this is your only computer), boot from it then live install Boot Repair (see 2nd option paragraph). It works miracles.

If you're feeling lucky, have a look at the [GRUB troubleshooting page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting), but this assumes you already know your way around your partitions. [This page](http://www.unixmen.com/fixing-a-few-common-grub-errors-broken-bootloader-and-error-1715/) contains interesting commands. The trick is to find out what X and Y values to use.

Don't ever mess with GRUB unless you know what you're doing. And of course, backup your disk before experimenting. Should anything go wrong, you can still restore it. Less pain at the end of the day.